# How can I change the IP of google cloud functions?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, geolocation, ip

**Introduction: **

- On Tuesday, 29/11/2022, Binance decided to limit its availability on futures API and trading API.
- Binance chose to go with geofencing and block multiple locations - including the USA.
- This caused havoc and problems in multiple services and bots that use binance data.
- In the fallout after - I reached out to the binance support via multiple channels and received the same response - "not our problem, discuss with google" (example: https://dev.binance.vision/t/google-cloud-and-ip-restriction-451-on-fapi-binance/13820/3)

**Problem statement: **

Is there a way to change the IP of my firebase functions for one OUTSIDE of US?

- I discussed with the support from Binance - they are not changing the limitation.
- I changed the region to asia-northeast1 still blocked. The IP is in the US (https://ip-geolocation.whoisxmlapi.com/lookup-report/eJ2av1WA5j) - I was hoping this would work and change the IP.

Comment: No, you cannot change the IP address of a function. You can route traffic to a VPC and add a NAT to use a fixed IP address. However, AFAIK all Google IP addresses map to the address of Google's headquarters in CA.

Comment: @JohnHanley - thank You. 
That was something I was expecting. 
Up, up and to the re-architecture board! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering as Community wiki, As mentioned by John Hanley in above comments.

You cannot change the IP address of a function. You can route traffic to a VPC and add a NAT to use a fixed IP address. However, As far as all Google IP addresses map to the address of Google's headquarters in CA.