# How can I make a cloud function test run from the region the function is set up in?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

[image]

I've set up my cloud function to run from London (europe-west2).  When I look at the address of the cloud function when deployed, it's from California: https://europe-west2-ltd-bot-397911.cloudfunctions.net/bet_placer

Is there a setting I must pay attention to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to the apparent geo lookup of the IP address of the hostname you were provided, that's expected. See:

- [How can I change the IP of google cloud functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74640622/how-can-i-change-the-ip-of-google-cloud-functions)
- [Why do Google Cloud Platform static IP addresses list Mountain View, CA in reverse lookup regardless of region assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988170/why-do-google-cloud-platform-static-ip-addresses-list-mountain-view-ca-in-rever)

> However, AFAIK all Google IP addresses map to the address of Google's headquarters in CA.

That doesn't mean your function doesn't run in europe-west2 region.  That's just the way the IP address was allocated. The traffic to that address still goes to London.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying to access a server that blocks IP addresses based on region.  Since the external IP was resolved to the US servers, I've decided to go down the route of having the cloud function deploy to a static IP.  Now even though I've set up all egress traffic to go through a static IP based in London (europe-west2), the destination server is receiving a request from the cloud function from Berlin (europe-west1).  I've configured my VPC to have just one subnet in London going through a gateway also set up in London through a connector.  Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: If you have a new problem with a new configuration, you should post a new question to describe that.